# How to send a list of integers as a request body in android using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

My Restful API expect a list of integer arrays. The API works fine when I use postman client to send an json array like so `[1,3,4]`.

I am using android volley to make requests. I have a list of integers which I want to send to the API like this.

```
    //converting integer array to a json array
    JSONArray myIntegerJsonArray = new JSONArray(myIntegerArray);

    String url = "myurl...";

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, myIntegerJsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            //... do stuff here
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    MySingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

I am currently getting `HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing` error. So I am guessing it's not sending the `myIntegerJsonArray` for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `POST` instead of `GET`